# Grab the title value by using parent()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html code:

```
<a class="ms-navedit-linkNode" title="Apps" href="url/test">
    <span class="menu-item-text">Apps</span>
</a>
```

I want to change the title value from "Apps" to something else.

Here is the javascript that Im using but it just gives my title variable `undefined`.

Note: Everything else works great in my js code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".menu-item-text").each(function() {
            var text = $(this).text();
            if (text == "Apps") {
                $(this).text("");
                $(this).text("Organization");

                var title = $(this).parent().attr("title");

                if (title == "Apps") {
                    $(this).parent().attr("title", "Organization");
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Is the problem with reading or updating? Can you drop a "debugger;" line right after the title assignment? You are also using a capitalized "Attr" in $(this).parent().Attr("title", "Test");

Comment: `<span>` tags don't have a `value` attribute, so `$(this).val("");` does nothing. Also, it's `parent().attr(`, with a lower-case `a`.  Did you try to debug this yourself, or even look at the JavaScript console?  You're also missing a `"` in `class="menu-item-text`.

Comment: so in your example you want to change "Apps" into "Organization" ?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Thanks for the notifactions I wrote the html code here thats why :) Yeah I checked everything and it seems that title is still at span .menu-item-text and title becomes undefined since there is no title. changed the A to lowercase still didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your html is missing a double quote

```
<a class="ms-navedit-linkNode" title="Apps" href="url/test">
    <span class="menu-item-text">Apps</span>
</a>
```

You also had a capital A on Attr. It should be:

```
$(".menu-item-text").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    if (text == "Apps") {
        $(this).text("Organization");

        var title = $(this).parent().attr("title");
        alert($(this).parent().attr("title"));

        if (title == "Apps") {
            $(this).parent().attr("title", "Test");
            alert($(this).parent().attr("title"));
        }
    }
});
```

I put both alerts to alert the title attribute, before and after it's changed.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VinnyFonseca/x8ceZ/

Comment: Thats weird I changed from A to a and it still doesnt work, and the html code was written here :> there is nothing wrong with it

Comment: Oh well there was another element around the span.. I love how Sharepoint generate elements :>

Comment: Also, as per other commenters suggestion and I agree, remove the val("") line. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ty6L2/).

Changes:

1. `$(this).val("");` to `$(this).text("");` (you can remove the statement altogether).
2. `$(this).parent().Attr("title", "Test");` to `$(this).parent().attr("title", "Test");`

Comment: No need to change what you're suggesting in #1. Just remove that line altogether. The next line takes care of what the OP actually wants (not sure why they have both) - `$(this).text("Organization");`